# how do i make sumif work with multiple columns

Tags: superuser

The below formula works fine for a single column, but I need it to sum across columns instead:

```
=SUMIFS(SrRecruiter!$F$2:$F$500,SrRecruiter!$A$2:$A$500,">="&'Monthly Team Scorecard Data'!$B$2,SrRecruiter!$A$2:$A$500,"<="&'Monthly Team Scorecard Data'!$C$2)
```

I am trying to sum data from column `F2:H6` using the below formula but it won't work is there a way to do this?  Thank you

```
=SUMIFS(SrRecruiter!$F$2:$H$6,SrRecruiter!$A$2:$A$500,">="&'Monthly Team Scorecard Data'!$B$2,SrRecruiter!$A$2:$A$500,"<="&'Monthly Team Scorecard Data'!$C$2)
```

Answer (score 0):

All,

I was able to get help from a user on a different Excel board who provided the below solution for my problem which works perfectly!  Perhaps this will help others in the future if needed.

=SUMPRODUCT(SrRecruiter!$F$2:$N$6*(SrRecruiter!$A$2:$A$6>='Monthly Team Scorecard Data'!$B$2)*(SrRecruiter!$A$2:$A$6<='Monthly Team Scorecard Data'!$C$2))